# ThreeJS: Play KeyFrameTracks of different animations

Tags: animation, three.js

I have two cubes and one KeyFrameTrack per cube (with different changing time and position data for each cube). I would like to display the KeyFrameTracks with following code:

```
// mesh of cube one
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
// cube two
mixer1 = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh1 );

var clipAction = mixer.clipAction( clip );
var clipAction1 = mixer1.clipAction( clip1 );

clipAction.play();
clipAction1.play();
```

However, only the first „clip“ gets played. How can I play both clips at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually updating both mixers in your animation loop? The code for this looks like so (assuming your organize your animation mixer in an array) https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/93e72ba7b24958ddb0652bd33171edd14ed2d693/examples/webgl_lights_hemisphere.html#L281-L285

Comment: Many thanks, I now have tried tweenjs and it‘s running as intended